# Strange Pylint Error on Python 3.7 import command

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, visual-studio-code, pylint

Been trying to use Pylint 1.9.2 with Python 3.7 and Flask 1.0.2 in visual studio code 1.25,

I keep getting the following error on Pylint on the first line of my code.

**F0002:: generator raised StopIteration**

```
{
"resource": "/d:/social network/models.py",
"owner": "python",
"code": "F0002",
"severity": 8,
"message": "F0002:<class 'RuntimeError'>: generator raised StopIteration",
"source": "pylint",
"startLineNumber": 1,
"startColumn": 1,
"endLineNumber": 1,
"endColumn": 1
}
```

I have no clue at all what is the cause of this error as it seems.

1. appear regardless of the content of my code(I tried "import datetime" and from peewee import *, both have the same error)
2. only appear in one file of the whole project. other files have module importation but see no errors of this one.

Please help if you have any idea what is causing this error!

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

PyLint 1.9.2 does not support Python 3.7.  Python 3.7 support is available from their preview release, which you can obtain with

```
pip install pylint astroid --pre -U
```

Comment: Thanks! Have roll back to Python 3.6.5 to wait for other module to catch up. Also encounter an unexpected error with peewee on python 3.7.

Answer (score 2):

Python 3.7 is supported now by pylint and astroid 2.X, you can grab them with pip. Currently pylint is at 2.1.1 while astroid is at 2.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pip install pylint astroid --pre -U` leads to an error, use

```
pip install pylint --pre -U
```

instead. This runs fine for me and this also updates astroid to the latest pre-release.